# Use Gitlab oauth service for Nexus3

Tags: gitlab, oauth, nexus

I've a brand new Nexus Repository Manager version 3.6.1 and a Gitlab 10.0.3. I'ld like to use Gitlab as a oauth provider for authentification (I'm already doing that for Jenkins & SonarQube). Seems it was possible with a plugin for Nexus 2, and Nexus 2 plugins are uncompatible with Nexus 3. I saw Nexus's LDAP authentification but that won't do for us.

So, did I missed an option, a plugin mechanism ?

Thanks for any thought on the matter !